# On which members the sum operator operates

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I don't know on which operators the sum operator operates? I was thinking all the operators till the identity matrix (including).

Here is the screenshot of the equation: [EQUATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt7Yg.png)

Here is the link to the paper describing the equation: [LINK](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniel-Choukroun/publication/265455600_Novel_Methods_for_Attitude_Determination_Using_Vector_Observations/links/5509c02b0cf26198a639a83c/Novel-Methods-for-Attitude-Determination-Using-Vector-Observations.pdf#page=258).

Comment: The dummy variable $i$ appears throughout, so it seems the whole thing is being summed

Comment: The sum is over the variable $i$, so probably any term with an $i$ subscript?

Comment: That seems like a valid point. Thank you.

Comment: The answer "must" be what the other two people said. Extremely awful notation - this should be clarified with parentheses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The scope of the sigma symbol ends with the identity matrix $I_3$.

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}&\left[3-\left({\bf r}_i^T{\bf b}_i\right)^2\right]I_3+\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i\right)\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i+{\bf r}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)
+\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)\left({\bf b}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)^T\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}\left[3-\left({\bf r}_i^T{\bf b}_i\right)^2\right]I_3\right)+\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i\right)\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i+{\bf r}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)
+\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)\left({\bf b}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)^T\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{q=1}^{n_k}\left[3-\left({\bf r}_q^T{\bf b}_q\right)^2\right]I_3+\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i\right)\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i+{\bf r}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)+\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)\left({\bf b}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)^T\\
\end{align*}

The scope of the sum is given by the surrounding parenthesis in (1). The index $i$ of the sigma symbol is a *[bound variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)*, whereas the other instances of $i$ are *free* variables.

But since the terms with the free variable $i$ do not occur elsewhere in the text, we can assume there is simply a typo and parenthesis are missing. We then have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}&\left(\left[3-\left({\bf r}_i^T{\bf b}_i\right)^2\right]I_3+\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i\right)\left({\bf b}_i^T{\bf r}_i+{\bf r}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)
+\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)\left({\bf b}_i{\bf b}_i^T\right)\left({\bf r}_i\times\right)^T\right)\\
\end{align*}